# write r output into r object and use them in the next code

Tags: r

I am still learning R and I have problem write and read frol a file in R.
What I am trying to do is retrieve at what iteration I am getting collinearity when I resampling and save them into a vector then. use this vector in the second code to ignore these iterations and get to the next iteration.

I have few errors in my code and you help please and give me better way to do this. but please keep in mind I need to save the iter vector into file so I can use it later.

Here is the code:

```
a0=rep(1,40)
a=rep(0:1,20)
b=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))
c0=c(rep(0,12),rep(1,28))
c1=c(rep(1,5),rep(0,35))
c2=c(rep(1,8),rep(0,32))
c3=c(rep(1,23),rep(0,17))
c4=c(rep(1,6),rep(0,34))
x=matrix(cbind(a0,a,b,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4),nrow=40,ncol=8)

sam <- function(n){
iterlist <- NULL
for(i in 1:n){
set.seed(i)
indx <- sample(1:nrow(x),nrow(x),replace=T)
samx <- x[indx,]
e <- crossprod(samx)
ee <- eigen(e)
evals <- ee$values
Zeval <- which(ifelse(abs(evals)<=1e-7,TRUE,FALSE))
if(length(Zeval)!=0) iterlist <- c(iterlist,i)
}
return(iterlist)
}
iter <- sam(20)
setwd("C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/R")
writeLines(iter)
readLines(iter)
fit <- function(dat,n){
for(i in 1:n){
if(i==iter) next
set.seed(i)
indx <- sample(1:nrow(x),nrow(x),replace=T)
samx <- x[indx,]
fit <- lm(rnorm(nrow(x),i,2*i)~samx-1)
bhat <- coef(fit)
}
return(bhat)
}
fit(x,20)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just combine your two functions into one so avoid duplicating identical code? That way you don't have to write anything out, read it back in, or do a bunch of other house cleaning items?

There was also an error in your `fit()` function on this line of code `norm(20,i,2*i)`

1. `norm` only expects two arguments, the first being a numeric matrix and the second a character vector specifying the type of matrix to be computed
2. Maybe you meant `rnorm()` instead? If that's the case - there's still an error because you create 20 random numbers while `samx` has a length of 40

I have no idea what you're really trying to do since you didn't tell us, so I'll leave it up to you to fix appropriately.

Finally - here's how I'd rewrite your two functions into one. I also reworked them to use an `*apply` function instead of your for loop. By iteratively making bigger objects, you'll make R crawl to a slow very quickly. Then you'll come back complaining about poor performance, so just don't iteratively grow objects in the first place! Either preallocate your storage vectors, or use an `*apply` function as I do here.

```
sam <- function(i){
    set.seed(i)
    indx <- sample(1:nrow(x),nrow(x),replace=T)
    samx <- x[indx,]
    e <- crossprod(samx)
    ee <- eigen(e)
    evals <- ee$values
    Zeval <- which(ifelse(abs(evals)<=1e-7,TRUE,FALSE))
    if(length(Zeval)==0)  {
      fit <- lm(norm(nrow(samx),i,2*i)~samx-1) #Note the assumption I had to make here
      bhat <- coef(fit)
    } else {
      bhat <- NA
    }
    return(list(bhat = bhat, iter = i))
}
```

And in use

```
> lapply(1:4, sam, 20)
[[1]]
[[1]]$bhat
      samx1       samx2       samx3       samx4       samx5       samx6       samx7 
 1.14857203  0.46875434  0.06780226 -0.56521389 -0.81897946 -2.48305129  0.56577183 
      samx8 
 2.34547722 

[[1]]$iter
[1] 1

...
...

[[4]]
[[4]]$bhat
[1] NA

[[4]]$iter
[1] 4
```

Also note I dropped the `n` argument from your fit function as you defined it but then didn't use it anywhere.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the explaination it is my bad, I have vvesion problem. I didn't see the errors in my code.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the explaination it is my bad, I have version problem. I didn't see the errors in my code. Also I notice there is an error in lapply(1:4,sam,20). First I can't compine the functions I just created an example similar to what I'm trying to do. All what I need to do is to save the iterlist vector so I can use thid vector in an other console or program.I create a function sam to obtain these bad iterations so I am trying to avoid them somewhere else in the code. Can you please show me how to save the vector so I can use it when ever? I need for loop because I need to use the next